# "Maximum call stack size exceeded" when adding new comment to a post

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to learn MEAN stack basics by following the tutorial here: https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack/opening-rest-routes. The goal of the tutorial is to design a Reddit clone, and I am experiencing a problem relating to adding user comments.

Whenever I attempt to add a comment to new post, I get error messages that seem to suggest recursive function calls are being made. This only happens on the *first* comment for a post. After reloading the server the comment is shown to be saved, and any further comments made on the post go through without any problems.

**Error Messages:**

```
events.js:180
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.split (<anonymous>)
    at get (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\get.js:9:22)
    at isBsonType (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:158:10)
    at clone (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:219:7)
    at cloneObject (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:321:17)
    at clone (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:205:16)
    at cloneObject (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:321:17)
    at clone (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:205:16)
    at cloneObject (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:321:17)
    at clone (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:205:16)
    at cloneObject (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:321:17)
    at clone (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:205:16)
    at cloneObject (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:321:17)
    at clone (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:205:16)
    at cloneObject (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:321:17)
    at clone (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:205:16)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4570:13
    at C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:264:16
    at model.<anonymous> (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:476:7)
    at C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\kareem\index.js:315:21
    at next (C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\kareem\index.js:209:27)
    at C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\kareem\index.js:182:9
    at C:\Users\drewg\OneDrive\Desktop\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\kareem\index.js:499:38
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

**My Post Model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  link: String,
  upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
  comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

PostSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
  this.upvotes += 1;
  this.save(cb);
};

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

**My Comment Model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  body: String,
  author: String,
  upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
  post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }
});

CommentSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
  this.upvotes += 1;
  this.save(cb);
};

mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

**The POST router where the error occurs:**

```
router.post('/posts/:post/comments', function(req, res, next) {
  var comment = new Comment(req.body);
  comment.post = req.post;

  comment.save(function(err, comment) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    req.post.comments.push(comment);
    req.post.save(function(err, post) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.json(comment);
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I believe it has something to do with the `req.post.comments.push(comment);` or `req.post.save(function(err, post)` lines, since when I comment them out, the error doesn't occur (but also the comment doesn't get sent to the server).

Comment: what is `req.post`? there is no express method called post in the `request` object.

Comment: It refers to the ```:post``` parameter id (I realized the tutorial chose some poor variable names that easily get mixed up)

Answer (score 0):

`comment.post = req.post;` i think `req.params.post`
`req.post.comments.push(comment);` i think just `post.comments.push(comment);` and also here `req.post.save(function(err, post) {` just `post.`

the naming is bad in this exemple because you are using post as you mongoose document `mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema)` model, i think (better 'PostModel'). and as params `/posts/:post/comments'` in route, i think :postId. and the request method is post `router.post`